# Two completely bogus duplicates votes

Tags: support

I can't decide whether this is a community or tech bug but [U.S. B1 Visa got refused under 214 (b)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83459/u-s-b1-visa-got-refused-under-214-b) it is certainly far from normal. What happened here ... ? Do we need better community processes to avoid a visa refusal question somehow voted to be the duplicate of "Are there caves and tunnels under Tallinn, Estonia?" or did the software go off the rails?

Comment: Apparently, in case of visa refusal one should hide in a cave in Estonia. Either that, or someone misclicked in the list of possible duplicates.

Comment: No idea, but I've remedied the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I also saw that. I don’t know how the tunnels got in there, but once a dupe target has been suggested it is in the list and must be removed manually by mods. Either somebody misclicked somehow or the software goofed badly. It’s hard for me to imagine how it could have happened, since the question IDs are so different. Luckily there was a link to the correct target somewhere in the comments so I was able to add that. (At least, I hope I did.)

If it were me, this would probably be [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: Well, two people voted on it, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered.

Comment: @pnuts Alas, I can’t do the norepro ;)